# Docker multiple apache vs single apache container

Tags: apache, docker, reverse-proxy

Wanted to ask about host load/performace.

Is host load higher if I run multiple containers each running apache and serving individual web pages. Plus another container running proxy server.
vs
running a single container with apache serving multiple websites.

Could anyone advice on which option is better/reccomended.

Thank you

Comment: Each approach has its own advantages and disadvantages. It really depends on your goals.

Comment: Well I am more concerned with host performance. At the moment I am running everything in one container. And one obvious disadvantage is that if I need to reboot docker all websites will be affected.
So for this one reason, I am thinking of splitting into multiple containers but am concerned with overstressing host and thus affecting all website's performance. What are your thoughts?

Comment: As @Henry said, it depends on variables like how many sites, what type of sites, expected traffic, etc. Analyze what you are working with then decide what is the best course of action. Running in separate containers should certainly help security if properly configured but doesn't quite scale as the all in one approach.